# Create rectangular shapefiles with specific length x width dimensions and orient them a specific direction using ArcGIS Pro 2.7

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-pro

I am trying to create rectangular shapefiles that are 200 ft x 300 ft (area = 60,000 ft^2, or 1.377 acres), and I am trying to orient them east and west according to the WGS84 projection system.

How can I create shapefiles that follow this criteria? In addition, I need to line each one of them up directly against each other, as illustrated below. Each rectangle is a bounding box with dimensions of 200 ft x 300 ft.

[image]

Note: I don't want to use a "grid" system because my field size is irregular, with some areas of the field will have more rectangular shapefiles, and some will have less.

I have experience creating shapefiles before, so I know how to start the process. However, I don't know how to customize them as requested.

Comment: The Create Fishnet utility is the Swiss Army knife of rectilinear geometry generation. You'd need to choose an appropriate coordinate reference, though, since geodesic rectangloids are not rectangular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WGS84 datasets are in units of decimal degrees so your requirement of feet won't work, you need to create a shapefile in a projected coordinate system for your region that uses feet as its units. That's your first step.

Once you have a correct dataset to capture your rectangles in then use the rectangle tool for your polygon layer. Click your first vertex then right click and choose length width for absolute distance, turn on snapping to help you align your rectangles.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That is the guidance that I needed.